# strategy for a situation when creating a simple version of a library

Tags: git, github, version-control, package-managers

## Situation

1. I have a package **A** which is a private package managed in github.
2. I want to create a simple version of package **A** named package **simple_A**.
3. developing of **simple_A** may have some good affect on **A** in the future.
4. I want **simple_A** to not be a private package. So I can't make **simple_A** to be a branch of **A**

## Question

What's the best strategy for this situation?

- Should I create a new project for **simple_A** ?
- or create a new branch of **A** and then create a fork on that branch ?

Answer (score 0):

Create a new project, it is very easy to integrate later on. Simply create a branch remotely on A then push your new project onto remote branch A

Comment: Then remote branch A is in a private package

Comment: that's not an issue you can push to wherever you want.

Comment: You mean then the simple A is a totally independent package ?